# Переход картинок на чистом Javascript

Tags: javascript

Всем привет. Возник такой вопрос. Как можно реализовать плавный переход картинок (заднего фона) на чистом Javascript? 
Заранее спасибо

Вопрос ещё в силе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сталкивался с похожей проблемой. Делал себе [фан-сайт по Majesty 2](http://majesty2.net/). Там у меня просто прозначный див должен был быть, и я заморочился его сделать именно без картинок прозрачным. В общем я думаю что без fake-подложки, то есть без дива, который будет позиционироваться под фон сайта, не обойтись. Ну а там уже opacity.

Можно конечно нашаманить, сделать переход между фонами через смены однотонных или градиентных картинок с разной прозрачностью, а их накладывать на контейнер уровня веше, чтобы текущий фон затенялся.

Answer (score 1):

Хм, боюсь без шаманств не обойтись. Первое что приходит на ум:

1. Сделать div (`position:relative;`), на весь родительский элемент (тот самый чей фон хотим плавно менять);
2. Положить на него текущий фон, сделать его не прозрачным (если пользователь начинает прокручивать колесиком мыши или тыкая на скроллбар, то придется перехватывать и прокручивать также картинку на этом диве);
3. Заменить фоновую картинку в родительском элементе, а дальше по таймеру делать фиктивный див постепенно прозрачным (opacity).

Таким образом получаем плавную смену, и самый кульминационный момент - разве эти красивости стоят того? :)

Comment: В данном случае мне нужно и важно реализовать это именно на чистом  JS. Картинки (или цвета) должны меняться по таймеру. 
Всё равно спасибо за ответ

Comment: Без CSS вы ничего не добьетесь. Да и кто вам мешает создавать дивы на лету и назначать им стили прямо в JS :)

Answer (score 0):

На *чистом* JavaScript такое не реализовать трудно. Но это довольно легко сделать используя [CSS](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9). Не стоит забывать, что стили для того и нужны. Если правильно сделать предварительную разметку, то свойство background, а это ваш задний фон, можно добавить и элементу html:

```
html {
    background: url(picture.png);
}
```

Теперь у вас есть два блока html и body с изображениями, которые накладываются (если правильно установить margin и padding у элемента body) друг на друга. Умелое управление свойствами opacity даёт вам желанный эффект.

Comment: К сожалению, не дает. Opacity влияет на потомков, в данном случае, body и получается так, что они также становятся прозрачными, в результате имеем мерцающий интерфейс. Лично сталкивался с этим в хроме.

Comment: В таком случае целесообразней сделать переход в цвет, а из него уже в картинку. Но это уже не то..

Comment: @Spirit, на мой взгляд при переходе из картинки в цвет, а потом из цвета в новую картинку может возникнуть проблема если на картинках преобладают разные (а ведь могут и диаметрально противоположенные) цвета.

Answer (score 0):

[Куча готовых вариантов](http://www.google.ru/search?q=jquery+background+stretch) На чистом css это сделать невозможно, а на JS вполне.